# Can I feed a cat wet dog food?

Tags: cats, diet

Recently I have been seeing two cats outside my window. They are friendly and one has a collar and is owned by the neighbors. I want to make sure the other cat has food and is ok but I don’t have any cat food. Would it be ok for right now to feed it dog food. Also any comments on what to do because I am concerned that the cat is owned but has no collar. Should I try to feed it?

Answer (score 3):

I would generally advise not feeding a cat that isn't yours. Often cats will go looking for someone else who will feed it but that's not always the best thing for the cat's health. Some cats can overeat and it's not uncommon that a neighbour is feeding the cat *as well as* the owner.

I would tend to avoid providing food to someone else's pet without talking to them about it first. Not least because the cat could have a special dietary condition and feeding it could result in harm for the cat.

As a compromise, you could always put out some nice fresh water for them and give them lots of fussing. If you're keen to feed the cat then you should probably speak to the owner before doing this.

Comment: RE: the first para - our neighbour's cat now has a collar reading "please don't feed me".  She's been ballooning despite being on a diet - when at home, anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Cats are strict carnivores while dogs are not.

It would be advisable to not give dog food to cats since dog food contains grain, vegetables and (usually) only little quantity of proteins.

Cat food, also, usually includes taurine additives since cats need it.

Comment: Thanks so much I’ll look into it!!